# Variation of "The secretary problem"

Tags: probability

I was assigned to write a computer program that simulates a CPU, but it is more like a game:
A queue of processes is initialized: $P_1,P_2...P_n$, ordered in some random permutation: $P_{\sigma (1)},P_{\sigma (2)},...,P_{\sigma (n)}$, where every process $P_i$ has a **priority**, $p_i\in\left \{1,2,...n  \right \}$.
The lower the value $p_i$ is, the more urgent $P_i$ is (in other words, if $p_i=1$, then $P_i$ has the highest priority in the queue).
In addition, every process $P_i$ in the queue, has its **relative priority**, $r_i\in\left \{1,2,...n  \right \}$, which, informally, represents "how urgent the process is relative to previous processes in the queue".
To be clear, let me give an example:
Let's say $n=6$: then the queue might look like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
P_i: & P_5 & P_6 & P_1 & P_2 & P_4 & P_3\\ 
p_i & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 6\\ 
r_i & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$$
as you probably already noticed, $r_i$ represents "What is $P_i$'s priority, related to all processes that precedes it in the queue". that's why, for example, although $p_1=2$, $r_1=1$, because related to $P_5$ and $P_6$, $P_1$ has the highest priority.
My goal is, of course, to choose the process with the highest priority.
There are two tricky parts though:
First of all, the CPU (my program) does not "know" $p_i$ (meaning, I don't get $p_i$ as input).
My program starts a loop, where on the $i$'th loop iteration, the CPU gets $r_i$ as input, and has to decide **on the spot**, only based on $n$ and $r_i$, whether if it rejects $P_i$ or accepts it. when the CPU chooses to accept some $P_i$, the game is over, and the real priority $p_i$ is revealed (if I reject the first $n-1$ $P_i$s, I'm obligated to accept $P_n$).
The second tricky part is, I don't get to regret. whenever I reject $P_i$, it's gone, and $r_{i+1}$ is presented. I can't go back and choose $P_i$ later in the game.
Some portion of my grade will evaluated based on how well my program makes its decisions: the program will get executed $m$ times, and the grade will be calculated by: $\text{decision_making}=100\times\frac{n-\text{avg}}{n-1}+20$
where $\text{avg=average of real priority over m program executions}$.

So I read some articles online, explaining how to deal with a variation of this problem, called [The secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), where they say that in order to get the best results, one should reject the first $\frac{n}{e}$ processes ($e$ - the base of the natural logarithm), and then accepts the first one that has $r_i=1$ (if no such process exist, I 'get stuck' with the $P_n$), I also saw a proof, showing that this tactic will give $37$~ percent success rate. So I tried it, and indeed got some pretty good results. I was able to achieve an average of $4$~ for $n=40$, giving $\text{decision_making}=109.743$, which is more than enough really. I was just wondering, out of curiosity; since this version is a bit different than the original "Secretary problem", does anyone have an idea that can improve this?
For example, how about the following tactics:
Let $i$ be the loop iteration, I'll reject the first $k=\frac{n}{e}$ processes in the queue, and for $i>k$, the closer $i$ gets to $n$ the less strict my policy will be; meaning, I'll start settle for $r_i=2,3,4...$ as $i$ grows towards $n$.
Could that be a better tactics?
Of course, I can write that code down and check, but I'd rather hear some opinions before introducing my code to new bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a variation of the Secretary problem - it *is* the Secretary problem.

The secretary problem is only concerned with relative ranking i.e. is the current candidate the best so far. The absolute value of the ranking is not known a priori - hence the difficulty.

Specifically, your problem is the [Cardinal Payoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem#Cardinal_payoff_variant) variant with the modification that the distribution from which the values are drawn is different - you have unique integers from 1 to $n$. This additional information should allow you to do slightly better than for the Uniform distribution case. To guide you on this - you need to consider the [German Tank Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) - specifically that in the first $c$ cases the expected maximum is $\frac{c(n+1)}{c+1}$.